# Azure Functions giving exception while loading Dependency Dlls

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have an Azure function which uses our custom dll (domain.dll), our dll internally has a dependency on LinqKit so we added the nuget package to our function but we get the below Exception --

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'LinqKit, Version=1.1.7.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc217f8844052a91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.,

We also tried directly adding the LinqKit.dll to the bin directory of the function and referencing it but still we get the same issue.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Only solution I could find: create a new function, copy and paste all over to the new function. Works.

Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to some good discussion here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/716

You must be using functions version 0.5 or greater for automatic package restore and list all packages in a package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, based on your update to the Github issue linked in Matt's answer, seems to be with the file name being used.

Azure Functions will process a file named `project.json`, and your file is currently named `Framework.json`